# Using 2 or more custom cellview in a collectionview

Tags: ios, collectionview

I'd like to recreate this app's view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CEqd.jpg

As you can see, the top part (store image and store name) is scrolled along with the products. The products (square images) looks like collection view cells. 
Is the store image & name part of the collection view and uses a different custom view cell in a different section?

What is the proper term for this user experience?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scroll view, then a ImageView for the store image, a view with a label for the store name and then you put a collection view

Comment: wouldn't the collection view have it's own scroller that's separate from the scroll view?

Comment: you can set scrollable to false